# How to activate and modify build configurations in cedet/ede?

Tags: emacs, cedet

I basically want to know how to turn off optimization so that gdb works correctly.

When I set up an Automake project from scratch, it seems like the defaults for CPPFLAGS are "-g -O2", but I just want "-g".  There is an unrelated question where the answer shows Project.ede files that have the configuration-variables field set for the target here:

[Setting up an emacs EDE-project with libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480144/setting-up-an-emacs-ede-project-with-libraries?rq=1)

Based on this, I edited my target to produce the following Project.ede:

```
;; Object test3
;; EDE Project Files are auto generated: Do Not Edit
(ede-proj-project "test3"
  :file "Project.ede"
  :name "test3"
  :targets (list 
   (ede-proj-target-makefile-program "test3"
    :name "test3"
    :path ""
    :source '("main.cpp")
    :configuration-variables '(("debug" ("CPPFLAGS" . "-g")) ("release" ("CPPFLAGS" . "-O3")))
    :ldlibs '("boost_program_options" "boost_system")
    )
   )
  :makefile-type 'Makefile.am
  )
```

However, executing ede-compile-project and ede-compile-target after these edits still produces the same "-g -O2" values.  How do I activate the "debug" configuration that I created?  Also, how can I set this to be the default set of configurations for new projects so I don't need to change every new project that I create manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change current configuration in project settings.

M-x customize-project, then go to the Settings tab and change the Current Configuration value.